# Some clarification of the uasort function

Tags: php, function

I need to use the [uasort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function, but I don't get how to get the arguments in the function... The given example is not so clear for me. How does the `cmp` function gets his arguments? Someone care to explain?

```
<?php
// Comparison function
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Array to be sorted
$array = array('a' => 4, 'b' => 8, 'c' => -1, 'd' => -9, 'e' => 2, 'f' => 5, 'g' => 3, 'h' => -4);
print_r($array);

// Sort and print the resulting array
uasort($array, 'cmp');
print_r($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in which elements are picked from the array shouldn't make any difference to the way in which your comparison function works.

`uasort` will be applied until every element in your array is sorted based upon the comparison you apply to it in your `cmp` function.

**Updated**

If you really want to know  how it's sorted, looking at the PHP source, the array first has `zend_hash_sort` applied to it which uses the `zend_qsort` comparison function which as far as I'm aware, just orders by value.

Try changing your cmp function to the below to see what's going on:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    echo "a=$a, b=$b"; // add this to see what's going on
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how does the `function cmp($a, $b)` get his arguments (`$a` and `$b`)?

Comment: PHP picks two elements from the array you pass to the uasort function to compare, you don't need to pass anything specifically.

Comment: But in this case, there are more then 2 items in the array... So how does PHP know which elements to take?

Comment: PHP iterates over the array, comparing the items many times to get them into the correct order. i.e. in the array {2,3,5,4} it would *probably* compare $a=2 and $b=3, then $a=3 and $b=5, then $a=5 and $b=4.

Comment: Presumably it's using the Quicksort algorithm ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort ) to do its work. So the `cmp` function will be called a number of times according to the Quicksort algorithm, each time being called with 2 entries from the array which the algorithm is trying to determine in which order they come.